# How to pass an expression "from higher level" to mutate?

Tags: r, expression

I would like to create a higher level function that wrap a mutate. I want to give an expression parameter to my function and being able to use this expression in mutate :

```
datas <- data.frame(x = sample(100))
fn <- function(datas, expr) {
   mutate(datas, flag = eval(substitute(expr), datas))
}

fn(datas[1], x > 50)
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'x' not found
```

But I don't understand why it fails since `mutate(datas, flag = eval(substitute(x > 50), datas))` works.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
fn <- function(df, expr)
eval(substitute(mutate(df, expr), list(expr=substitute(expr))))
```

or (preferably) this:

```
fn <- function(df, expr)
mutate_(df, .dots= list(flag=substitute(expr)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is probably to use `dplyr::mutate_` which is designed for this kind of scenario when non-standard evaluation is problematic within a function.

```
fn <- function(datas, expr) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  dplyr::mutate_(datas, flag = expr)
}
```

See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#calling-from-another-function and `vignette("nse")`.

**Updated 2018-06-21:**

As pointed out by @danilinares, the preferred syntax for `dplyr` has changed since this question was first raised. With newer versions of `dplyr`, tidy evaluation and quosures are used. So the example here would be:

```
library(dplyr)
fn <- function(datas, expr) {
  expr <- enquo(expr)
  mutate(datas, flag = !!expr)
}
```

More info is available in the [dplyr programming article](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: mutate_ is deprecated, this is the new framework https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: @danilinares Originally answered well before `rlang::eval_tidy` and quosures, but now updated to support the newer sytnax.